# How can I remove caulk?

Tags: caulk

The caulk between the quartz backsplash and counter behind my kitchen sink needs to be replaced.  How can I remove the old caulk?

Comment: a hair dryer can help soften most types. but elbow grease will be required no matter what. Pull out what you can, dig/scrape the rest with a credit card, plastic scraper or single-edge razor blade, being careful not to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully take a utility knife and cut a "beginning" point and then see if you can just pull it out in a continuous strip. If that doesn't work, then you'll just have to continue using the utility knife to cut out the caulk but be careful not to scratch the surfaces. After it's all out, scrape the surfaces lightly with a single edge blade to remove any remaining particles. Then wipe the area with some regular vinegar to remove any stubborn residue. You can then re caulk with a quality silicone caulk. Smooth out the caulk line by dipping your finger in some water and lightly going over the caulk. I've heard that dipping  your finger into alcohol works great but I haven't tried it. Good luck

Comment: I thought you were supposed dip your tongue in the alcohol. Sorry couldn’t help myself.  But I use utility blades or single edged blades and water. Cooking oil also helps but makes two big of a mess for me. The water/oil helps prevent scratching. Keeping a sharp blade is important if you get a burr that is going to cause scratches.

Comment: @Ed Beal   That's after you've finished the job...lol

Answer (score 0):

I have had some luck using a chisel.  I found it easier to control and get under the caulk while pulling at the caulk with some needle nose pliers.  It is a delicate job though and you can scratch the counter easily.  Lubricating the blade sounds like a good idea though and I would try it the next time I’m trying to remove old caulking.